# Kohana 3 Pagination, how to set a max page links limit?

Tags: php, pagination, kohana

Im using the Kohana Pagination module.

My pages numbers, "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc. " starts to get too many numbers, and fills the page quite alot. (as i get more and more data).

How can i set a max limit, like only showing up to 10 "page links"?

As right now i have page links from 1 to over a thousand, which looks and fills alot.

Comment: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/pagination - look for the rendering style - and tell which kohana version you're using.

Comment: @Hakre i use the classic, just render(). I would like to use the "Digg" or extended, but when i do render('digg') it says the view does not exists error.

Comment: Just seeing, you're using version 3, my fault did over-read that in the title. It now takes a view for pagination, check Fenec's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'floating' view instead of basic. You can set 'count_in' property there.

https://github.com/kohana/pagination/blob/3.1/master/views/pagination/floating.php